# Remove unicode characters from mysql query flask python

Tags: python, html, mysql, unicode, flask

I browsed many links but didn't get a solution. I have results of sql query in cursor. They are int, strings etc. I am trying to show to it directly on html by passing it in rendertemplate and looping in html file. The problem is that I get useless characters which are '' 'u' etc which I don't want. I understand they are unicde but I am unable to remove them. I have tried many things to remove them but my attempts are in vain. Attached is my code.

```
query= ("""select Forrent.Property_id, Societyname  from ForRent,property where Type = 'Residential'; """)
   cursor.execute(query)
   cnx.commit()
   #rentable rsidential
   print "rentable resdential called"
   result =cursor

   return render_template('ViewPropertyfromMain.html', result = result)
```

And this is my html file. all i want is to show the result id under id heading and society name under its column heading.

```
                <table border="1" style="width:auto">
                    <tr>
                    <th style= "font-size:35"> Property_id</th>
                    <th style= "font-size:35"> Society</th>

                  </tr>

                        {% for row in result %}
                            <tr>
                                <td style= "font-size:35">{{ row }} </td>

                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}

                </table>
```

Comment: It's because you're printing the whole row, which will be a list/dict of Unicodes - Python will show a representation using litterals

Comment: Are you seeing `\u1234` in the table?  Or only after `SELECTing`?  That is, how did you insert the Unicode characters?

Comment: Incidentally the SQL query also looks doubtful, did you really mean to do a cross-join of all the rows in `ForRent` with all the rows in `property`? I suspect you mean something like `FROM ForRent JOIN property ON property.id=ForRent.Property_id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
                  {% for row in result %}
                        <tr>
                            {% for val in row %}
                                <td style= "font-size:35">{{ val }} </td>
                            {% endfor %}

                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
```

you have to iterate over the row ... the fact that its unicode or str really wont matter :P

Comment: MAN! IT WORKED! Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `str` on each string that you are passing to the template. For example, if result is iterable, you can try something like this

```
cleaned_result = [str(i) for i in result]
```

Comment: while this will attempt to convert to ascii bit str (reasonably likely to have a UnicodeDecode error) ... I doubt this is quite what OP is actually looking for ... I could be wrong ...

Comment: In Python 2.x, this break at the first non-ASCII char